# Error while loading ngx-bootstrap css on angular 5

Tags: angular5, ngx-bootstrap

Getting error while loading css on angular5 with ngx-bootstrap

`Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

i have include css only in index.html

  `<link href="../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the style in your `.angular-cli.json`, if you're using ng-cli. Then Angular CLI will take care of adding the file to index.html for you:

```
{
  ...
  "styles" : [
    "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "../../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
    "styles.scss",
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

Alternatively, if not angular-cli, then webpack can take care of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following inside of your link tag :

```
type="text/css"
```

Best regards